# Unity3d: Rotation of game object

Tags: unity, rotation, quaternion

```
Quaternion objectRotation = Quaternion.identity;
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
objectRotation *= rotation;

gameObject.transform.rotation *= objectRotation;
```

here `angle = -90`

But the gameobject isn't rotating as desired,
when I replaced

```
gameObject.transform.rotation *= objectRotation;
```

with

```
 gameObject.transform.Rotate (0,0,angle);
```

Then the gameobject rotated -90 degree, dont understand why the Quaternion part isn't working? It rotated 90 degrees

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, the first snippet works fine. My object rotates from (0, 0, 0) to (0, 0, -90)

Comment: @Hellium Do the both method behave the same way?

Comment: Yes, the quaternion rotation and `Rotate` call gave me the same result.

Comment: @Hellium Are the both offset or fixed? For example, if a object has already been rotated by 30 degree , then after adding this , will it be 90 or 120?

Comment: Supposing `angle = -90` ; **Quaternion method** : (0, 0, 0) => (0, 0, -90) ; (10, 20, 30) => (10, 20, -60) ; **Rotate method** : (0, 0, 0) => (0, 0, -90) ; (10, 20, 30) => (10, 20, -60) (**same result**)

Comment: Maybe, you should deal with `localRotation` instead of `rotation`, especially if you have parents already rotated.